# F#: Proper `try` blocks inside an async{} block?

Tags: asynchronous, async-await, f#

To simplify my scenario, let's suppose I have this simple code:

```
let someCondition = false

let SomeFuncThatThrows () =
    async {
        if someCondition then
            raise <| InvalidOperationException()
        return 0
    }

let DoSomethingWithFoo (foo: int) =
    Console.WriteLine (foo.ToString())

let SomeWrapper () =
    async {
        let! foo = SomeFuncThatThrows()
        DoSomethingWithFoo foo
    }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    Async.RunSynchronously (SomeWrapper ())
    0
```

When executing it, it obviously just prints "0". However, some day, circumstances change, and some external factor makes `someCondition` become `true`. To prevent the program to crash in this scenario, I want to handle the exception. Then for an F# newbie it's easy to change SomeWrapper adding a try-with block, which most people would think that works:

```
let SomeWrapper () =
    async {
        let! foo =
            try
                SomeFuncThatThrows()
            with
            | :? InvalidOperationException ->
                Console.Error.WriteLine "aborted"
                Environment.Exit 1
                failwith "unreachable"
        DoSomethingWithFoo foo
    }
```

However, this above doesn't work (the exception is still unhandled), because SomeFuncThatThrows returns a successful result: an `Async<int>` element. What throws an exception is the `let! foo =` bit because it awaits the async workload.

However, if you want to change SomeWrapper to fix the exception handling, many may think this is possible:

```
let SomeWrapper () =
    async {
        let foo =
            try
                let! fooAux = SomeFuncThatThrows()
                fooAux
            with
            | :? InvalidOperationException ->
                Console.Error.WriteLine "aborted"
                Environment.Exit 1
                failwith "unreachable"
        DoSomethingWithFoo foo
    }
```

But no, the compiler is not happy, as it signals the following error:

> /.../Program.fs(17,17): Error FS0750: This construct may only be used
>   within computation expressions (FS0750) (SomeProject)

Then, it seems the only way I could fix it is this way:

```
let SomeWrapper () =
    async {
        try
            let! foo = SomeFuncThatThrows()
            DoSomethingWithFoo foo
        with
        | :? InvalidOperationException ->
            Console.Error.WriteLine "aborted"
            Environment.Exit 1
            failwith "unreachable"
    }
```

However, I'm not 100% happy with this solution, because the try-with is too wide, as it also covers the call to DoSomethingWithFoo function, which I wanted to leave outside the try-with block. Any better way to fix this without writing non-idiomatic F#? Should I report the compiler error as a feature-request in Microsoft's F# GitHub repo?

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the call to `SomeFuncThatThrows` in a new `async` that contains a `try...with`:

```
let SomeWrapper () =
    async {
        let! foo = 
            async {
                try
                    return! SomeFuncThatThrows()
                with
                | :? InvalidOperationException ->
                    Console.Error.WriteLine "aborted"
                    Environment.Exit 1
                    return failwith "unreachable"
            }
        DoSomethingWithFoo foo
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Any better way to fix this without writing non-idiomatic F#?

In idiomatic F# and functional code, we try to get rid of using exceptions and side-effects as much as possible.

`Environment.Exit` is a big side-effect, don't use it.

If `SomeFuncThatThrows()` must be able to throw exception (because e.g., you cannot modify its source code). Then try to wrap it inside a safe function which returns an `Option` value and use this function instead.

Your whole code can be rewritten as:

```
let someCondition = true

let SomeFuncThatThrows () =
    async {
        if someCondition then
            raise <| InvalidOperationException()
        return 0
    }

let SomeFunc () =
    async {
        try
            let! foo = SomeFuncThatThrows()
            return Some foo
        with _ ->
            return None
    }

let DoSomethingWithFoo (foo: int) =
    Console.WriteLine (foo.ToString())

let SomeWrapper () =
    async {
        match! SomeFunc() with
        | Some foo -> DoSomethingWithFoo foo
        | None -> Console.Error.WriteLine "aborted"
    }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    Async.RunSynchronously (SomeWrapper ())
    0
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @nilekirk works and encodes directly the logic that you were looking for, but as you noted in the comments, it is a fairly complex syntactic structure - you need a nested `async { .. }` expression.

You could extract the nested `async` block into a separate function, which makes the code much more readable:

```
let SafeSomeFunc () = async {
    try
        return! SomeFuncThatThrows()
    with
    | :? InvalidOperationException ->
        Console.Error.WriteLine "aborted"
        Environment.Exit 1
        return failwith "unreachable"
}

let SomeWrapper2 () = async {
    let! foo = SafeSomeFunc ()            
    DoSomethingWithFoo foo
}
```

Here, we actually need to put some return value into the `with` branch.

Comment: I didn't write -1, @nilekirk did :) and your first suggestion was already mentioned in my question ;)

Comment: @knocte Oops, sorry! I should learn to read questions more carefuly!

Comment: no worries; I removed the -1 from his answer, if you don't mind I can also edit your answer